# Label not adjusting text correctly with Auto Layout enabled in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I'm using Storyboard to layout the UI for an app and I'd like to use Auto Layout. I'm usually able to resolve my own issues with Auto Layout, but I've hit a wall here with one label that does not want to re-size properly or show any text at all.

Here's a screenshot of the simulator:

[image]

In the attributes inspector I have Lines set to 0 and Line Breaks set to Word Wrap:

[image]

I've tried "Resetting to Suggested Constraints" for the entire UITableViewController:

[image]

I've also tried selecting the labels themselves and Pinning the width and the height, as well as adding any missing constraints:

[image]

However, it only shows the first four characters of the address:

[image]

The table cell for the Address label is correctly adjusting to 88 points because of this method I implemented, but still something still obviously off:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        return 88;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 2) {
        return 88;
    }
    else {
        return 44;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it, however, I don't know if it's the best solution.

I tried just about everything to try and get the two labels in the table cell to play well together.
Ultimately, I'd like the detail label frame to expand as needed for the address to populate.

I ended up selecting both the Address label and the Detail label on the Storyboard and choosing the default "Reset to Suggested Constraints" in the current view.

Then I set an explicit width in the size inspector for the detail view:

[image]

That along with this method seems to work OK:

```
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
      return 88;
  }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 2) {
      return 88;
  }
    else {
      return 44;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The latter part is on the right track but you have set a "greater than or equal to" constraint and autolayout is choosing to go with the "equal to" rather than making it any wider.

You need to figure out why. I'd start by setting a fixed width constraint on the label "Address" and then setting a constraint fire the left side of your address field to equal the right side of the address label, while pinning them to the right and left of the respective container to keep them attached to the sides. That may fix it.

For the earlier part where you see nothing, it's quite likely the field is being displayed entirely outside its parent container, which is clipping to bounds. Orange dotted lines often indicate this location in the interface builder preview and it is a sign there are insufficient constraints set.